# PVM library (Parallel virtual machine) installation problems when use make

Tags: c, makefile, cc, pvm

I'm trying to install PVM library (https://netlib.org/pvm3/pvm3.4.6.tgz) 
I successfully extracted the package in my $HOME 
Following the Readme instructions I have set my env variable PVM_ROOT=$HOME/pvm3 at the end of my $HOME/.bashrc file and I have append the content of the file $HOME/pvm/lib/bashrc.stub to the .bashrc and uncommented the lines 'export PATH=$PATH:$PVM_ROOT/lib/PVM_ARCH' and 'export PATH=$PATH:$PVM_ROOT/bin/PVM_ARCH'
After reopening the bash all my env variables are there so I guess it's all good until there.

But THEN I go in ~/pvm3 an when I type 'make' I get a list of warning the first time:

Here is a sample of the warnings I get when running make the first time

```
cc  -DIMA_LINUX -I../../include -I../../tracer -I../../src -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -c ../../console/job.c
../../console/job.c:150:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  150 | job_init()
      | ^~~~~~~~
../../console/job.c:175:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  175 | job_free(jp)
      | ^~~~~~~~
../../console/job.c:224:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  224 | obuf_free(jp, op)
      | ^~~~~~~~~
../../console/job.c:240:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  240 | obuf_dump(jp)
      | ^~~~~~~~~
../../console/job.c:252:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  252 | checkoutput(jp, cc, len, cod, src)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

it ends with:

```
cc  -I../../include -I../../src -DIMA_LINUX -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -c ../../pvmgs/pvmgroups.c
../../pvmgs/pvmgroups.c:37:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   37 | main()
      | ^~~~
../../pvmgs/pvmgroups.c: In function ‘main’:
../../pvmgs/pvmgroups.c:41:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gs_getgstid’; did you mean ‘gs_gettid’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   41 |  gstid = gs_getgstid();
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |          gs_gettid
cc  -I../../include -I../../src -DIMA_LINUX -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -o pvmgroups pvmgroups.o libgpvm3.a  -L../../lib/LINUX -lpvm3  
cp pvmgroups ../../bin/LINUX
cp libgpvm3.a ../../lib/LINUX
case xt in xt ) echo ranlib; ranlib ../../lib/LINUX/libgpvm3.a ;; esac
ranlib
cp pvmgs ../../lib/LINUX
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/pvmgs/LINUX »
done building group server and library
make[1] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3 »
```

if I try again I get this message:

```
./lib/aimk -here -f ./conf/`./lib/pvmtmparch`.def -f ./Makefile.aimk default
making in . for LINUX
make[1] : entering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3 »
building in src
cd src; ../lib/aimk CC="cc" F77="f77" install
making in LINUX/ for LINUX
make[2] : entering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/src/LINUX »
make[2]: nothing to do for « install ».
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/src/LINUX »
done building in src
building tracer
cd tracer; ../lib/aimk CC="cc" F77="f77" install
making in LINUX/ for LINUX
make[2] : entering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/tracer/LINUX »
ar rcv libpvmtrc.a trcmess.o trcfile.o trccompat.o trccompatglob.o trcutil.o trclib.o
r - trcmess.o
r - trcfile.o
r - trccompat.o
r - trccompatglob.o
r - trcutil.o
r - trclib.o
ranlib libpvmtrc.a
cc -O  -DIMA_LINUX -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -o tracer tracer.o cmd.o trcglob.o -L../../lib/LINUX -L../../tracer/LINUX -lpvmtrc -lpvm3 
cc -O  -DIMA_LINUX -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -o trcsort trcsort.o -L../../lib/LINUX -L../../tracer/LINUX -lpvmtrc -lpvm3 
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/tracer/LINUX »
done building tracer
building console
cd console; ../lib/aimk CC="cc" F77="f77" install
making in LINUX/ for LINUX
make[2] : entering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/console/LINUX »
cc  -DIMA_LINUX -I../../include -I../../tracer -I../../src -DSYSVSIGNAL -DNOWAIT3 -DRSHCOMMAND=\"/usr/bin/rsh\" -DNEEDENDIAN -DFDSETNOTSTRUCT -DHASERRORVARS -DCTIMEISTIMET -DSYSERRISCONST -DNOTMPNAM -DUSESTRERROR -DSYSVSTR -DHASSTDLIB -DSYSVBFUNC  -o pvm cons.o cmds.o job.o trc.o  -L../../tracer/LINUX -L../../lib/LINUX -lpvmtrc -lpvm3 
cp pvm ../../lib/LINUX
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/console/LINUX »
done building console
building libfpvm
cd libfpvm; ../lib/aimk CC="cc" F77="f77" install
making in LINUX/ for LINUX
make[2] : entering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/libfpvm/LINUX »
make[2]: nothing to do for « install ».
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/libfpvm/LINUX »
done building libfpvm
building group server and library
cd pvmgs; ../lib/aimk CC="cc" F77="f77" install
making in LINUX/ for LINUX
make[2] : oentering directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/pvmgs/LINUX »
make[2]: Nothing to do « install ».
make[2] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3/pvmgs/LINUX »
done building group server and library
make[1] : leaving directory « /home/thesylio/pvm3 »
```

I don't know if it worked but anyway I tried calling pvm and it kind of worked:

```
~/pvm$ pvm
pvm> halt
halt
completed
```

xpvm command is unfound though and
I thought that it was alright so tried one of the code examples given in pvm3/examples

```
$ cc -o hello hello.c
hello.c:37:10: fatal error: pvm3.h no such file or directory of this type
    37 | #include "pvm3.h"
       |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

fine, the documentation at http://www.netlib.org/pvm3/faq_html/node62.html gives an answer for this kind of problems

```
$ cc -o hello -I$PVM_ROOT/include hello.c
hello.c:39:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   39 | main()
      | ^~~~
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/ccEvHgbT.o : in function « main » :
hello.c:(.text+0x1e) : undefined reference to « pvm_mytid »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x51) : undefined reference to « pvm_spawn »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x69) : undefined reference to« pvm_recv »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x7f) : undefined reference to « pvm_bufinfo »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x8e) : undefined reference to « pvm_upkstr »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0xc4) : undefined reference to « pvm_exit »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I then followed this website http://parallel.vub.ac.be/documentation/pvm/troubleshooting.html#compile2

```
$ cc -o hello -I$PVM_ROOT/include -L$HOME/pvm3/lib/pvm3 hello.c
hello.c:39:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   39 | main()
      | ^~~~
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/ccmzt4MN.o : in function « main » :
hello.c:(.text+0x1e) : undefined reference to « pvm_mytid »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x51) : undefined reference to « pvm_spawn »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x69) : undefined reference to« pvm_recv »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x7f) : undefined reference to « pvm_bufinfo »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0x8e) : undefined reference to « pvm_upkstr »
/usr/bin/ld : hello.c:(.text+0xc4) : undefined reference to « pvm_exit »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried with gcc and cc, I tried on different distributions: kali-rolling 2020.3 on a 64bits computer and ubuntu-20.04.1 on a 32 and 64bits computer.
I plan to try with cshell instead of bash but I think it's the makefile that makes it difficult or maybe I did not specify the architecture well enough. I'm also not a regular C coder so I might have done some obvious mistake.
I would also install it on windows 10 but let's not rush things ahah
Thanks for your time

Comment: Seems you need to install m4 in order to run the makefile

Comment: You're right, I updated the question